# When a new module is added to the ISS, do they still do the "Shake" test?

Tags: iss, docking-port, mir

I recall reading, that when Mir would get a new module added, after it was docked, a cosmonaut would stand in, feet on one wall, hands on the other, and try to shake it, to ensure the docking seal was completed properly.

The maneuver was called the **Rezonans** (or Resonance) experiment. It occurred on Soyuz 26 / Salyut 6 / Soyuz 27 <sup>[1][2]</sup> and on MIR EO-1 with Soyuz T-15 / MIR / Progress 25 <sup>[3][4]</sup>.

Do they still do this for new modules at the ISS?

Does it differ US vs Russian side, perhaps due to the different nature of the docking/berthing connectors?

That is, compare the CBM vs PMA vs Russian Active vs Russian Passive docking ports.

1. [Soyuz 27 Mission](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-27.htm)
2. [Soyuz: A Universal Spacecraft By Rex Hall, David Shayle pp.226](https://books.google.com/books?id=dbGchpi1HP8C&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=Rezonans+spacecraft)
3. [Space Technologies, Materials and Structures
   edited by B. Paton, pp. 507](https://books.google.com/books?id=2wIoqbYm0lIC&pg=PA507&lpg=PA507&dq=Rezonans+spacecraft)
4. [Encyclopedia Astronautica: Mir EO-1](http://www.astronautix.com/flights/mireo1.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not aware of any structural dynamics tests conducted on the ISS using crewmembers as 'excitation sources'.  However, the ISS does have a build-in [structural dynamics sensor system](http://sem-proceedings.com/24i/sem.org-IMAC-XXIV-Conf-s20p03-Space-Station-Truss-Wireless-Instrumentation-Structural-Dynamics.pdf) consisting of accelerometers and strain gauges.  [This paper](http://sem-proceedings.com/19i/sem.org-IMAC-XIX-190102-Structural-Dynamics-International-Space-Station-Using-Data-from-Laser.pdf) describes some early tests where a laser imaging system was also used.  Jet firings and spacecraft dockings probably provide more than enough excitation for the structural dynamics sensor system.